# How to know the specific URL of each year in a dropdown menu of a webpage

Tags: html, r, url, get, rvest

I am scraping this webpage which shows the PDFs of flights of authorities in Brazil. I couldn't find out the specific URL of each year (2018, 2017... 2013) shown in the dropdown menu.

http://www.fab.mil.br/voos/

The default webpage shows the PDFs related to 2019.

Checking on 'network', after clicking to see the code, I have seen that 'Form Data' is VoosForm%5Bano%5D=2017 or VoosForm[ano]: 2017.

But, even adding this information to the base URL, the webpage is still showing the PDFs related to 2019, and not to 2017, for example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(downloader)

dir.create("~/Downloads/PDFvoosFAB")
setwd("~/Downloads/PDFvoosFAB")

url <- "http://www.fab.mil.br/voos"

urls <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  `colnames<-`("link")

urls_voo <- urls %>%
  filter(str_detect(link, "fab.mil.br/cabine/voos/"))

i <- 1

while(i < 142) {
  tryCatch({
    pdf_file <- as.character(urls_voo$link[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    Sys.sleep(2)
    download.file(pdf_file, basename(pdf_file), mode = "wb")
    Sys.sleep(5)
  }, error = function(e) return(NULL)
  )
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Comment: Please include your current code

Comment: I have included the code, but my doubt isn't related to the code, but to the URL. Could you give me a help?